# How to enable trigger, function in AWS RDS Postgresql

Tags: amazon-rds

I am trying to add a trigger function to AWS RDS Postgresql, looks like the query run successfully the update trigger is getting added and trigger function is getting added but when I update the table the trigger is not executing. howerver when I run the same trigger query in locally installed Postgresql db it is working properly.

I also saw a similar post which is for enabling AWS RDS Mysql trigger, I am wondering if anyone has any idea on how we can enable AWS RDS Postgresql trigger function would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_trg_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE 'plsql'
AS $$
DECLARE BEGIN
    IF new.emp_age > 65 THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Age is greater than 65'
    END IF;
RETURN new;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER emp_trg
BEFORE UPDATE ON emp_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_trg_func()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your AWS RDS Postgresql following parameter in RDS group parameter is set to origin, as replica will prevent execution of triggers in AWS RDS Postgresql

session_replication_role (enum) #
Controls firing of replication-related triggers and rules for the current session. Possible values are origin (the default), replica and local. Setting this parameter results in discarding any previously cached query plans. Only superusers and users with the appropriate SET privilege can change this setting.

The intended use of this setting is that logical replication systems set it to replica when they are applying replicated changes. The effect of that will be that triggers and rules (that have not been altered from their default configuration) will not fire on the replica. See the ALTER TABLE clauses ENABLE TRIGGER and ENABLE RULE for more information.

PostgreSQL treats the settings origin and local the same internally. Third-party replication systems may use these two values for their internal purposes, for example using local to designate a session whose changes should not be replicated.

Since foreign keys are implemented as triggers, setting this parameter to replica also disables all foreign key checks, which can leave data in an inconsistent state if improperly used.